# Create an utf-8 csv file in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, csv

I can't create an utf-8 csv file in Python.

I'm trying to read it's docs, and in the [examples section](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-examples), it says:

> For all other encodings the following
>   UnicodeReader and UnicodeWriter
>   classes can be used. They take an
>   additional encoding parameter in their
>   constructor and make sure that the
>   data passes the real reader or writer
>   encoded as UTF-8:

Ok. So I have this code:

```
values = (unicode("Ñ", "utf-8"), unicode("é", "utf-8"))
f = codecs.open('eggs.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
writer = UnicodeWriter(f)
writer.writerow(values)
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
line 159, in writerow
    self.stream.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 686, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can someone please give me a light so I can understand what the hell am I doing wrong since I set all the encoding everywhere before calling UnicodeWriter class?

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

Comment: It seens the problem is with the codecs.open. When I remove it and just use open, it works. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to use `codecs.open`; `UnicodeWriter` takes Unicode input and takes care of encoding everything into UTF-8. When `UnicodeWriter` writes into the file handle you passed to it, everything is already in UTF-8 encoding (therefore it works with a normal file you opened with `open`).

By using `codecs.open`, you essentially convert your Unicode objects to UTF-8 strings in `UnicodeWriter`, then try to re-encode these strings into UTF-8 again as if these strings contained Unicode strings, which obviously fails.

Comment: How exactly did I try to encode twice, since I just opened a file object? Isn't codec.open just opened a file object stream indicating it's encoding?

Comment: According to the docs of `codecs.open`: "Open an encoded file using the given mode and return a wrapped version *providing transparent encoding/decoding*.". In other words, if you open a file for writing with `codecs.open`, it will transparently encode everything you write into it to UTF-8 first.

Comment: I thought "providing transparent encoding/decoding" was too subjective. I think if I need to understand more I just have to read the source.

Answer (score 1):

As you have figured out it works if you use plain open.

The reason for this is that you tried to encode UTF-8 twice. Once in

```
f = codecs.open('eggs.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
```

and then later in UnicodeWriter.writeRow

```
# ... and reencode it into the target encoding
data = self.encoder.encode(data)
```

To check that this works use your original code and outcomment that line.

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the csv / unicode challenge a while back and tossed this up on bitbucket: http://bitbucket.org/famousactress/dude_csv   .. might work for you, if your needs are simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "double-encode" everything.

Your application should work entirely in Unicode.

Do your encoding only in the `codecs.open` to write UTF-8 bytes to an external file.  Do no other encoding within your application.

Comment: Csv module doesn't work with unicode. To make my code work, I have to remove exactly the codecs.open.

Comment: If CSV doesn't work with unicode then you cannot use it to create UTF-8, unless you want to write your own UTF-8 encoder.