# Writing unicode data in csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I know similar kind of question has been asked many times but seriously i have not been able to properly implement the csv writer which writes properly in csv (it shows garbage).

I am trying to use UnicodeWriter as mention in [official docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-examples) .

```
ff = open('a.csv', 'w')
writer = UnicodeWriter(ff)
st = unicode('Displaygrößen', 'utf-8') #gives (u'Displaygr\xf6\xdfen', 'utf-8')
writer.writerow([st])
```

This does not give me any decoding or encoding error. But it writes the word `Displaygrößen` as `DisplaygrÃ¶ÃŸen` which is not good. Can any one help me what i am doing wrong here??

Comment: Are you sure that you are *viewing* a.csv with the right encoding?

Comment: No i am not sure, i am just opening that csv file. How to do that?

Comment: I have used text import wizard of excel and i defined utf-8 encoding there, the data is shown correct. Can we define encoding of csv file in code so that i do not have to use this wizard? Also if i use codecs.open and then i try to write unicode data then it will cause problems which is mention here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085263/create-an-utf-8-csv-file-in-python

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the file's encoding. If you're displaying the file somewhere that isn't set to unicode you'll get that error though. for example, on a Linux box if I try to cat a file with non-ASCII characters in it on a terminal when my locale is set to for example ASCII, I'll get garbled text like that.

Comment: In most editors, you can set the 'encoding' in 'File' or 'View' menu. E.g. in Scite you can choose utf-8 from File->Encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing a file in UTF-8 format, but you don't indicate that into your csv file.

You should write the UTF-8 header at the beginning of the file. Add this:

```
ff = open('a.csv', 'w')
ff.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
```

And your csv file should open correctly after that with the program trying to read it.

Comment: ff = open('a.csv', 'w')
ff.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
writer = UnicodeWriter(ff)
writer.writerow([unicode('Displaygrößen', 'utf-8')]) and when i open file it still does not show properly. I do not want to use import wizard of excel. Your answer is what i want, but its not working

Comment: @AamirAdnan This is the way to go with Excel and UTF-8 csv files as input. If you still has a conversion issue, I would suspect o-umlaut in your Python interpreter in translated into ascii characters before it reaches the unicode() function, and you're fooled by Python here. Is your .py script saved in utf-8 format ?

Comment: @AamirAdnan Try to confirm what I suspect by using the unicode encoded version of o-umlaut by setting this string in your script `'Displaygr\xc3\xb6ßen'`, it will be .py file ascii-proof

Comment: thanks for all of your help, yes you were write i was fooled by Python. I have fixed that script encoding. But now i am seeing `Displaygren` in csv file where `öß` is omitted from word. I am now only defining encoding in script at top # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @AamirAdnan you're right, the Eszett would have need also being encoding to get the output ; the best practice if you're dealing with non-ascii strings in yours scripts is definitely to get your scripts saved as utf-8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10971/discussion-between-boud-and-aamir-adnan)

Comment: Do not write a BOM when using utf8.

Comment: He's writing utf-8 csv files for Excel, thus yes write a BOM for that case

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file with [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) should fix it.

Comment: I have wrote content and now i am manually opening the file on windows to see what it writes. I don't need to open the file through program.

Comment: Either your porblem is that the wrong content is written (this could be the case when you open it *without* codecs) or that you haven't configured your editor properly, but it's more likely that the wrong data is written. Try writing the same data with a file handle from `codecs.open`