# how to add lists to a dictionary then output to .csv

Tags: python, html, csv, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm try to iterate through tables in html by a searchlabel, then update the found value to a dictionary, then write those values to a csv. The output currently works for both the url and the headline, but the name output will either be blank or show "None." If i print the output of blog["name'] however, it is correctly pulling the information I want. I suspect that it's an indentation error but I can't figure out where to line things up. I've tried moving things around but nothing seems to work to get the name assignment to work inside that loop.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import my_csv_writer

def td_finder(tr, searchLabel):
    value = ""
    index = tr.text.find(searchLabel)
    if index>-1:
        tds = tr.findAll('td')
        if len(tds)>1:
            value = tds[1].text
return value

def main():
    topdir = 'some_directory'
    writer = my_csv_writer.CsvWriter("output.csv")
    writer.writeLine(["url", "headline", "name"])

    """Main Function"""
    blog = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        for f in files:
        url = os.path.join(root, f)
        url = os.path.dirname(url).split('some_file')[1]

        if f.lower().endswith((".html")):
            file_new = open(os.path.join(root, f), "r").read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(file_new)
            blog = {}

            #Blog Title                    
            blog["title"] = soup.find('title').text

            for table in soup.findAll("table"):
                for tr in table.findAll("tr"):
                    #name
                    blog["name"] = td_finder(tr, "name:")

        seq = [url, unicode(blog["title"]), unicode(blog.get("name"))]

        writer.writeLine(seq)

#return ""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print "Finished main"
```

Comment: what is going on with the line `blog["name"] = td_finder(tr,name:'`

Comment: sorry, typo - I corrected it. It's just a general holder for a searchLabel in the tr_finder function.

Comment: Your `main` function isn't correctly indented (after `def main():` there should be an indentation).

Comment: stack is a pain to input code in. indents corrected. this is what it looks like in my ide.

Comment: tip for stack is to use spaces for your indentation then, just add another indent to your code and paste it in!

Comment: the return for td_finder is still outside of the function, and after `for f in files:` you need to indent that whole block one level more until `writer.writeLine(seq)` fairly sure that's not the problem as you get a message when you try to run this code that the return is out of the function, and the indentation error. I've indented it correctly [here](http://pastebin.com/UyygtQRR), but as I said I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: I indented so it'll write for every .html, but it still isn't writing the blog["name"]. I've tried adding a print right after it finds the name and that works perfectly - it is definitely finding the info I want, just not writing it to the .csv.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing unicode strings to a csv file which according to the official docs "The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode...".

It does offer alternative classes to enable different encodings [via UnicodeWriter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples). The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481738/writing-unicode-data-in-csv) from Boud on SO highlights the need to set the desired encoding in the CSV file.

Comment: I have tried the print statements. This "So because the key doesn't appear to exist, this returns None." I'm fairly certain is my issue. I can't figure out why after the td_finder() correctly finds the html tag and info I want, by the time I write my sequence it's gone.

Comment: Does the "name" text need to be in unicode? What happens if you convert it to ASCII?