# django write Unicode to CSV file

Tags: django, csv, unicode, ascii

Everyone knows CSV file can not read UTF-8 chars, I been searched for lots of posts but still can not find a good solution.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Same question as [Writing unicode data in csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481738/writing-unicode-data-in-csv?rq=1)?

Comment: yes, but i still not get it ~.  :(

Comment: what you don't get? if you wants to have help you should explain what's your problem. we are all able to read minds, but it's difficult when we are with PCs.