# issue in writing data from 2 RDDs (one with unicode data and one with normal )into a csv file in PySpark?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have two `RDD's`:

**RDD1:** data in `RDD1` is in unicode format

```
[[u'a',u'b',u'c'],[u'c',u'f',u'a'],[u'ab',u'cd',u'gh']...]
```

**RDD2:**

```
[(10.1, 10.0), (23.0, 34.0), (45.0, 23.0),....]
```

Both the `RDDs` have same number of rows (but one has 2 columns/elements in each row/record and one has 3). Now what I want to do is take all elements from `RDD2` and `2nd` record from `RDD1` and write them out to a `csv` file **on the local file system (not hdfs)**. So the output in the `csv` file for above sample will be:

```
a,b,c,10.0
c,f,a,34.0
ab,cd,gh,23.0
```

How can I do that in `PySpark`?

**UPDATE:** This is my current code:

```
columns_num = [0,1,2,4,7]
rdd1 = rdd3.map(lambda row: [row[i] for i in columns_num])

rdd2 = rd.map(lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1]+ (tup[0]/3)) if tup[0] - tup[1] >= tup[0]/3 else (tup[0],tup[1]))

with open("output.csv", "w") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for (r1, r2) in izip(rdd1.toLocalIterator(), rdd2.toLocalIterator()):
        writer.writerow(r1 + tuple(r2[1:2]))
```

I am getting error as `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`. If I do `writer.writerow(tuple(r1) + r2[1:2])` then I get error as `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)`
`

Answer (score 2):

If by local you mean driver file system then you can simply `collect` or convert `toLocalIterator` and write:

```
import csv
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    from itertools import izip
else:
    izip = zip

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(10.1, 10.0), (23.0, 34.0), (45.0, 23.0)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([("a", "b" ," c"), ("c", "f", "a"), ("ab", "cd", "gh")])

with open("output.csv", "w") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for (r1, r2) in izip(rdd2.toLocalIterator(), rdd1.toLocalIterator()):
        writer.writerow(r1 + r2[1:2])
```

Comment: If you use Python 2 and your data contains characters that cannot be encoded using ascii you'll have reencode or create rows manually without help of csv writer.

Comment: How can I do that? I think in my data there is a text like `2\x80` and that is why I am getting the error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18766955/1560062, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3085263/1560062, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5838605/1560062

Comment: thanks! One thing though, is it possible to write to the csv file using `csv writer` with `;` as the `delimiter` and not `,`?